# Android development

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\BrainTrain\app\src\main\res\mipmap-hdpi\USER-PC.eml: Error: The file name must end with .xml or .png

This error as been occurring ever after closing my Android studio

Comment: not sure what you are trying to say

Answer (score 0):

You put a file, named `USER-PC.eml` in `res/mipmap-hdpi/`. That is not a valid filename for that directory (wrong extension, dashes not allowed), and quite possibly it is not a valid *file* for that directory.

So, remove it from the project for now.